# How to change class in Ogre Battle 64?

Tags: ogre-battle

I've got enough sets of items, but the attributes graph has red in it for certain attributes. I'm assuming that means I'm not high enough in the attribute, but it might just mean I'll lose that much if I change to the class. I've also got enough sets of the class, since I just bought 5.

It's not listed in the [old site](http://ogrebattle64.8k.com/index.html) I used to use, either.

Do I just level up a fighter a bunch and eventually his stats will be high enough?

Comment: Also note that alignment is _incredibly_ difficult to control.  If your unit is at 100% alignment and you want to grow into a class that requires low alignment, that unit has to survive around 42 battles against high alignment units.  Fighting any low alignment units can make that take even longer.  Also fighting units lower in level drops alignment and fighting units higher in level raises it. A little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the gamefaq [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/n64/198230-ogre-battle-64-person-of-lordly-caliber/faqs/9203), the stats are also a requirement, but it has to be the base stats, not the boosted ones.

> Q: Why can't I advance in class?
>
> A: There are several requirements to being able to advance in class.
>   The very first thing you need to do is find the basic set of equpiment
>   for your target class.  What you want is to check shops whenever you 
>   enter a new area and find any equipment you have none of, then buy it.
>
> The other requirements are simple in comparison.  You'll need to have 
>   reached specific levels in your physical attributes and experience 
>   level.  Also, you'll need to be at a specific alignment for most 
>   classes.
>
> Q: Why can't I get (insert class here)?  I have everything I need!
>
> A: Obviously, you don't.  Remember, you need the proper stats, 
>   alignment, and equipment for a class to appear on the board.
>
> Q: Okay.  I have all the stats, alignment, and equipment, but I STILL 
>   can't get the class!  What's wrong?
>
> A: One last thing.  Make sure your stats are not increased past their 
>   limit due to a weapon or armor modifying your strength.  The class 
>   limits are derived from BASE stats, not one's increased to due to 
>   equipment.